# Why can't I see the Physics button on the world panel?

Tags: game-engine, physics, world

I'm starting to make physics in blender, but when I was going to edit the parameter "gravity" on the "World => physics" button, I found it nowhere!

Can someone please help me? What can I do? I need it for my animation assignment.

It is like the first image when it should include the buttons shown in the second one.

Here I have the world panel, but the "physics" subdivision is nowhere to be seen

[image]

It should be like this. Sorry for the spanish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are in the "Scene" section, not on the world.

[image]